# Unable to resolve dh-modaliases

Tags: drivers, ati, gui

I installed Ubuntu 13.10. I have issue that my GUI is really slow. So I'm trying to install new drivers to ATI Radeon HD 6310. I downloaded driver and trying to compile it

```
sudo sh amd*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/saucy
```

it starts all process, but after few seconds I'm getting

```
Unable to resolve  dh-modaliases.  Please manually install and try again.
```

I google it but I couldn't find anything what could tell me where I could find this package.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a bit late, the package `dh-modaliases` is in Ubuntu repos https://pkgs.org/download/dh-modaliases and might be needed to rebuild a dkms package (kernel driver) on another debian-based distro ([zstd support in debian dpkg missing issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=892664))..

To recompress a (ubuntu) zstd.deb to (debian) .xz, you can use a

```
podman run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/cwd ubuntu dpkg-deb --raw-extract /cwd/[zstd DEB FILENAME]{,.d}
dpkg-deb --build [zstd DEB FILENAME].d
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to install dh-modaliases with:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-mod*
```

Comment: There's no `dh-mod` package.